# Python - name for file not correct - loop error

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

i have a script which reads a html file and from this file it extracts the relevant lines. but i have a problem when printing the filename. the file names are source1.html source2.html and source3.html. Instead it prints source2.html source3.html, source4.html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os.path

n = 1
filename = "source"+str(n)+".html"
savefile = open('OUTPUT.csv', 'w')

while os.path.isfile(filename):
    n = n+1
    strjpgs = "Extracted Layers: \n \n"
    file = open(filename, "r")
    filename = "source"+str(n)+".html"


    soup = BeautifulSoup (file, "html.parser")

    thedata = soup.find("div", class_="cplayer")
    strdata = str(thedata)

    DoRegEx = re.compile('/([^/]+)\.jpg')
    jpgs = DoRegEx.findall(strdata)
    strjpgs = strjpgs + "\n".join(jpgs) + "\n \n"
    savefile.write(filename + '\n')
    savefile.write(strjpgs)

    print(filename)
    print(strjpgs)

savefile.close()
print "done"
```

Comment: Increment `n` (and update your filename) at the end of your loop instead of at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define n as 1, then in your WHILE you immediately increment it to 2. By the time you get to the print(filename), n is 2 and filename has been changed to "Source2.html". Move the printing or move the variable increment.

Comment: This is exactly it. Just need to open the file before doing n += 1 (or n = n+1).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your print statement at the beginning of your loop, and your increment at the end, for the next iteration:

```
while os.path.isfile(filename):
    print(filename)

    strjpgs = "Extracted Layers: \n \n"
    file = open(filename, "r")
    filename = "source"+str(n)+".html"
    soup = BeautifulSoup (file, "html.parser")

    thedata = soup.find("div", class_="cplayer")
    strdata = str(thedata)

    DoRegEx = re.compile('/([^/]+)\.jpg')
    jpgs = DoRegEx.findall(strdata)
    strjpgs = strjpgs + "\n".join(jpgs) + "\n \n"
    savefile.write(filename + '\n')
    savefile.write(strjpgs)

    n = n+1
    print(strjpgs)
```

Comment: Wouldn't he not need to move his open() function?

Comment: I understand your line of thinking fully, it would solve the issue and should print exactly what he wanted, but I believe OP is likely planning to gather much more information, and if the value of n is wrong, but you are just printing the correct values before increasing it, then it's going to be problematic for other features.

Answer (score 0):

You made a logical mistake because you increment the variable n before you store it. Simplest solution will be define your variable to 0 instead of 1. Next mistake is that you never close the html files therefore use **with open("filename", 'w') as file:** this close your file automatically when out of scope and it is more pythonic.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os.path

n = 1
filename = "source"+str(n)+".html"
savefile = open('OUTPUT.csv', 'w')

if os.path.isfile(filename):

    strjpgs = "Extracted Layers: \n \n"
    while True:
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            filename = "source"+str(n)+".html"

            # parsing things...

            savefile.write(filename + '\n')
            savefile.write(strjpgs)

            print(filename)
            print(strjpgs)

        if filename == "source3.html":
            break
        else:
            n+=1

savefile.close()
print ("done")
```